# Adding an AirPlay Route Button to AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

Is there any way to add an AirPlay Route Button to AVPlayerViewController? I've tried the MPVolumeView trick but that doesn't appear to work with AVPlayerViewController.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have airplay devices available, the button will just appear. If you don't see it, make sure you've configured the AVPlayerViewController's AVPlayer to opt in (by setting its `allowsAirPlayVideo` property).